# Fake UINavigationController slide animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an app, where I need to have so much navigation controllers and in every navcontroller I have all elements (buttons, images, etc.) the same except two uilabels. Customer wants to have "sliding" animaiton when switching between navcontrollers like instagram app has. I was wondering if there is any possibility to "simulate" switch of two navigationcontrollers and just change uilabels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lot of UIViewControllers have the same UIBarButton items,I strongly suggest you to have a common superclass like "BaseViewController". 
Every UIViewController will be a subclass of BaseViewController and not of the standard UIViewController.

With this pattern you can configure your default UINavigationBar on BaseViewController by adding the buttons and images which are always present and customize it only when you need it (by adding the UILabels you are talking about)

The instagram animation is the default iOS animation you achieve by pushing a new UIViewController onto the navigationController stack with this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

To reply to your question on the comment section:

It's already left to right,but if you want you can animate from right to left also.Check this out:

```
YourViewController  *pageView = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.45;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pageView animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to change the direction of the animation (from left to right)?

Comment: I edited the answer to reply to your second question

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunattely I'm getting an error `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.` Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: That's probabily an autolayout issue,but I think it's not related with the original question. Open another question if you can't solve it and post a screenshot of you .xib or your storyboard